# How can I define the Columns of a Silverlight DataGrid outside of the DataGrid in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid nested in a UserControl like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class=MyUserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <datagrid:DataGrid x:Name=myDataGrid />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I use this UserControl in my Silverlight Application:

```
<UserControl x:Class=MainPage>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <MyUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Is there anyway I can define the DataGrid.Columns property of myDataGrid inside MyUserControl from MainPage in XAML? I tried passing in a style targeting DataGrid, but I couldn't use Columns as a Property in the Setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Add to your control a property that exposes the datagrid columns:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> MyColumns
{
    get { return myDataGrid.Columns; }
}
```

That's it. Now you can write something like:

```
<my:GridControl>
    <my:GridControl.MyColumns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Edad" />
    </my:GridControl.MyColumns>
</my:GridControl>
```

Comment: Wow, this worked.The solution was much easier than I though.Thank you so much!!